# GetElementByID no recoje datos ¿?

Tags: javascript

Buenas amigos y gracias de antemano. Pues lo dicho, no sé por qué no funciona este GetElementById. No me recoje los datos en la constante

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" id="formulario">
    <input type="text" id="texto" placeholder="ingrese el texto">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="boton">
</form>
<script>
    const contenido = document.getElementById("texto").value;
    function mostrar(){
        alert(contenido);
    }
    boton.onclick = mostrar;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estás obteniendo el valor del input `"texto"` al cargar la página. Cualquier cambio posterior no es detectado. Puedes solucionarlo moviendo esa línea a la función `mostrar`:

```js
function mostrar(){
    const contenido = document.getElementById("texto").value;
    alert(contenido);
}

boton.onclick = mostrar;
```

```html
<form action="" id="formulario">
    <input type="text" id="texto" placeholder="ingrese el texto">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="boton">
</form>
```

Por otro lado, te recomiendo no usar la variable global `boton`: aunque funciona en todos los navegadores, está recogido por el estándar como una funcionalidad *heredada* que se mantiene por retrocompatibilidad, pero no es aconsejable usarlo (seguramente sea eliminado con el tiempo, en próximas versiones del estándar). En su lugar te recomiendo definirla por ti mismo:

```
const boton= document.getElementById('boton');
```

Comment: Ouh yeah!
Muchas gracias Pablo

Answer (score 5):

La referencia al `input` no se encuentra en el contexto de `mostrar()`, por lo tanto no obtiene el valor.

Aparte de lo que te dice @PabloLozano, siempre conviene poner tu código dentro del listener `DOMContentLoaded`, para esperar a que todo el DOM esté cargado antes de usar cualquier elemento del mismo. Esto, aparte de ser la práctica recomendada, ayuda a entender cómo organizar el código.

Si por ejemplo necesitas referirte **al elemento `input`** en varias partes del código, puedes crear una referencia al mismo dentro de listener `DOMContentLoaded` y luego usar esa referencia para obtener el valor allí donde lo necesites.

Por ejemplo aquí creamos una referencia **al elemento** en  la la constante `elContenido` y luego, dentro de la función invocamos a `elContenido.value`. Así, dentro de cualquier función que necesites ese valor, sólo tendrás que usar `elContenido.value`, obteniendo el valor que tenga el elemento **en ese momento**. El elemento es constante en el DOM, pero el valor del mismo puede cambiar, por tanto debes invocar `value` **allí donde lo necesites**.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  const elContenido = document.getElementById("texto");
  const elBoton = document.getElementById("boton");
  elBoton.onclick = mostrar;

  function mostrar(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //Evitar que se recargue la página
    console.log(elContenido.value);
  }


});
```

```html
<title>Document</title>
<form action="" id="formulario">
  <input type="text" id="texto" placeholder="ingrese el texto">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="boton">
</form>
```

Comment: buenísima recomendación!
Muchas gracias A. Cedano

Answer (score 0):

Solo quería agregar/aclarar que al estar `<script>` antes de la finalización de `body` se va a ejecutar después de que todo el contenido de `body` se haya cargado. Esto quiere decir que la query (`getElementById`), podría estar fuera de la función, y de hecho es preferible para que no realice la misma evaluación en cada click. Lo que **no puede estar fuera** es `.value`, porque de otra manera tenemos solo el valor inicial. Ejemplo:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="" id="formulario">
    <input type="text" id="texto" placeholder="ingrese el texto">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="boton">
  </form>
  <script>
    const contenido = document.getElementById("texto");//<-- Puede estar fuera, y es preferible.

    function mostrar() {
      alert(contenido.value);//<-- .value tiene que estar aquí si queremos el valor actualizado
    }
    boton.onclick = mostrar;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```